# transfer specific index of array to a new array - php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to delete an index from array and insert it into in new array. I want two things which i tried to explain one is

```
Array
    (
        [index1] => Deleted
        [index4] => Inserted
    )
     Array
(

        [index3] => test
        [index4] => Inserted
    )
     Array
    (

        [index2] => numbers
        [index3] => test
        [index4] => Inserted
    )
     Array
    (
        [index1] => Deleted

    )
```

now i want if arraysize is 1

```
 foreach($array as $arrays){
    array_push($array1,($arrays[0]));
      unset ($arrays[0]);

 }
```

i want to remove

```
Array
    (
        [index1] => Deleted

    )
```

from `$array` and `$array` to be

```
 [index1] => Deleted
```

second is if `$array` is

```
Array
(

    [index2_123] => numbers
    [index3_level] => test
    [index4_test] => Inserted
)
```

i want a new array with `$array1` as

```
Array
(

    [index3_level] => test

)
```

and `$array1` is modified to

```
Array
(

    [index2_123] => numbers
    [index4_test] => Inserted
)
```

Comment: $array1=array();
    array_merge($array1,$array[2]);
    unset($array[2]); //try this

Comment: should also unset $array[4]

Comment: this is not even transfering $array[2] value into $array1

Comment: So you want to split array according to even and odd index??

Comment: no not for odd and even . I want to do it for any index

Comment: What you mean by any index? Can you please elaborate? Check my answer? @Rozeena

Comment: You mean you want to split into 2 array right ? not bothered about index ?

Comment: yes . split on any choice of indexes i want

Comment: it can be $array(index 3) and $array1(index1 , index2 index4)

Comment: "Rozeena *split on any choice* - what a rule?

Comment: something like this if array size is 4 push $array[index 4] into $array1 and remove $array[index 4] from $array

Comment: if another count? or you looking for code only for 4 ?

Comment: we don't know what you want, please explain everything in detail

Answer (score 2):

Try this way,

```
$arr = Array
    (
        'index1' => 'Deleted',
        'index2' => 'numbers',
        'index3' => 'test',
        'index4' => 'Inserted'
    );
$arr1 = $arr2 = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($i%2 == 0){
        $arr1[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        $arr2[$key] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Output

```
$arr1
Array
(
    [index1] => Deleted
    [index3] => test
)

$arr2
Array
(
    [index2] => numbers
    [index4] => Inserted
)
```

And if you don't need that value then you can use it as

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    if($i%2 == 0){
        $arr[$key] = $value;
    }else{
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    $i++;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [index1] => Deleted
    [index3] => test
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through them and generate the array -

```
$new = array();
foreach($yourarray as $key => $val) {
    $index = str_replace('index', '', $key); // get the key index
    if($index % 2 != 0) { // check for odd or even
        $new[$key] = $val; // set the new array
        unset($yourarray[$key]); // delete from the main array
    }
}
```

**Update**

For any index use a counter

```
$i = 0;
$new = array();
foreach($yourarray as $key => $val) {
    if($i % 2 != 0) { // check for odd or even
        $new[$key] = $val; // set the new array
        unset($yourarray[$key]); // delete from the main array
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: hi i don't want to specify it for odd or even . it can be any index

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `array_flip` and `array_diff_key` to filter the first array, then use `array_diff` filter the second:

```
$specificIndex = array('index1', 'index3');
$array1 = array_diff_key($array, array_flip($specificIndex));
$array2 = array_diff($array, $array1);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/6rR04).

**If** you want get in an array only certain elements of your choice you can do something like:

```
$specificIndex = array('index1', 'index3');
$selectedItem = array_intersect_key($array, array_flip($specificIndex));
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/vn1XS).

Comment: `<?php

$array = array(
        'index1' => 'Deleted',
        'index2' => 'numbers',
        'index3' => 'test',
        'index4' => 'Inserted',
);

$specificIndex = array('index1', 'index3');
$array1 = array_diff_key($array, array_flip($specificIndex));
$array2 = array_diff($array, $array1);

print_r($array1);
print_r($array2);` instead if `$array2` can we have updated value in `$array`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
        'index1' => 'Deleted',
        'index2' => 'numbers',
        'index3' => 'test',
        'index4' => 'Inserted',
);
$specificIndex = 'index3';
$array1=array();
foreach($array as $key => $value){
if($key==$specificIndex){
 $array1[$key] = $value;
unset($array[$specificIndex]);
}
}
print_r($array);
print_r($array1);
```

http://3v4l.org/TvZ19

Comment: Add more information on how this answers the OP's question.

Comment: `$specificIndex` taking only one value at a time how can more indexes can be given to it at a time `$specificIndex = 'index2','index3';`